# How to get the click on self linked anchor tag using its class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the value of **ID attribute** of the **anchor** tag when it is clicked .

```
<a href="#" id="a'.$id.'" class="delete_assessor delete-row"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

         $(".delete_assessor").live("click",function(){
            alert('delete');
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var trhandler = 'a'+id;


            if(confirm("Do you really want to delete this assessor ?")){
                ajax("delete_assessor",$(this).attr("id"),trhandler);

            }
        });
});
```

Am not able to alert any values and in console it is not showing any message

```
alert('delete');
console.log('clicked');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of jQuery 1.7, the **[.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** method is deprecated. Use **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** to attach event handlers. Also add **[`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)** for preventing default behavior or click event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".delete_assessor").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    alert('delete');
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var trhandler = 'a' + id;
    if (confirm("Do you really want to delete this assessor ?")) {
      ajax("delete_assessor", $(this).attr("id"), trhandler);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="a'.$id.'" class="delete_assessor delete-row"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>ggg</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much . Wasted around 2hrs for this one :)

Answer (score 1):

That is because `.live()` is deprecated in version 1.7 and removed in version 1.9. You should use `.on()` instead of `.live()`

```
$(".delete_assessor").on("click",function(){
   //rest code....
});
```